# How to hide console in Magick++

Tags: c++, qt, graphicsmagick

I use Magick++ (as part of GraphicsMagick) and Qt. When I call Image::read(), the console window dcraw.exe appears for a few seconds. How can I hide it?

Qt 5.9.2 (QMainWindow)

GraphicsMagick-1.3.26-Q16

MinGW-w64 32bit

Code:

```
    Magick::Image image;
    image.read(path.toStdString());
```

and in the main function:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        Magick::InitializeMagick(*argv);
    ...
```

[image]

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: I have not noticed this in an application which links the graphicsmagick library. Are you sure you are not running a script which loads the image using a shell command of dcraw?

Comment: @eyllanesc updated

Comment: @KennyOstrom yes, looks like Magick++ running a script which loads the image using a shell command of dcraw.

Comment: Can you recreate with the sample code which uses Image.read("girl.gif") in http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/Image.html?

Comment: @KennyOstrom the console window will open only if i read RAW format (no GIF). `image.quiet( false );` irrelevant - console window will open always when i read RAW image.  GraphicsMagick using dcraw for read RAW image. The read command written in the modules.mgk file: `<delegate decode="dcraw" command='dcraw -w -O "%o" "%i"' />`